# I can't enlarge the image in the navbar

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/epWYL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHEq8.png)

I want to enlarge the logo in the navbar, but the size does not increase, no matter what value I change. What should I do?

I was only able to change the position of the picture. Other than that, nothing I tried - to change the size - worked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using px and % in place of rem or em may be that will work